# How to add ECS attributes to an instance using terraform

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs

I heavily use [ECS Attributes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/put-attributes.html) on our containerized infrastructure. I couldn't find terraform docs to achieve this. Do I need to execute aws cli commands manually to apply those attributes after creating the infrastructure?

Comment: Cross posted at https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/2939/249

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd recommend having the ECS agent set the ECS attributes if you need these.

You can do this by adding [`ECS_INSTANCE_ATTRIBUTES`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-agent-config.html#ecs-instance-attributes) to the `/etc/ecs/ecs.config` file or passing them as an environment variable directly to the ECS agent on startup.

If you have a "base" ECS AMI (either one you rolled your own or the Amazon Linux AMI) then you probably just want to use user data to dynamically set this from Terraform.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Works perfectly with terraform

Answer (score -2):

You can use "**aws_ecs_service**" resource and add attributes. For example:

```
placement_constraints {
type       = "memberOf"
expression = "attribute:ecs.availability-zone in [us-west-2a, us-west-2b]"}
```

Comment: Yes we can use attributes this way. But how to add ECS attributes to an instance using terraform?